# Obtener elemento por data-dt-idx o valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Estoy usando DataTables para generar una tabla, y en esta se cargan los ultimos 10 registros. Tambien tengo un boton que permite agregar 10 registros mas (los 10 ultimos antes de los anteriores) y asi. Lo que pasa es que este boton trae bien los ultimos diez registros, pero queda en la pagina 1 y quisiera que cuando hace clic en el boton de agregar registros vaya siempre a la ultima que se va creando por DataTables. Este seria el codigo del ul que se va generando:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li class="paginate_button previous" id="tabla-historial_previous"></li>
    <li class="paginate_button active">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="tabla-historial" data-dt-idx="1" tabindex="0">1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="paginate_button">
        <a href="#" aria-controls="tabla-historial" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Entonces quiero saber si hay alguna forma de obtener el ultimo elemento, o el elemento de mayor data-dtx o texto.
Gracias.

datatables:

```
$('#tabla-historial').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "searching": false,
        "search": false,
        "dom": "itp",
        "ordering": false,
        "info": false,
        "ajax": {
            'type': "POST",
            'url': "/ABM/Cliente.aspx/CargarHistorial",
            'contentType': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            'data': function (d) {
                d.fd = fechaDesde;
                d.fh = fechaHasta;
                d.op = operador;
                d.ca = campo;
                return JSON.stringify(d);
            },
            'dataSrc': function (msg) {
                var json = JSON.parse(msg.d);
                cerrarLoader();
                return json.Data;
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            { data: "FechaModificacion" },
            { data: "Campo" },
            { data: "DatoRemplazado" },
            { data: "DatoNuevo" },
            { data: "Operador" }
        ],
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: 0, render: function (data) {
                    return moment(data).format('DD-MM-YYYY | HH:mm');
                }
            }
        ],
        destroy: true
    });
```

Comment: quisiera saber por qué haces eso, es necesario? por qué no mejor haces una paginación por ajax con datatables? en fin, te recomiendo este artículo para que sepas cómo ordenar de manera ascendente o descendente un campo de la tabla una vez refrescada aquí https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: Se esta usando Ajax, ahi edite la pagina porque aca no me deja poner el codigo por cantidad de caracteres

Comment: Y si, es para no sobrecargar la db, entonces se pide de a pocos registros y si es necesario se van agregando mas con el boton

Answer (score 0):

```
$($(".page-item active").context.activeElement).data("dtIdx")
```

*devuelve el "data-dt-idx" de el numero de paginación actualmente seleccionada*

debe existir alguna manera mas sencilla pero esta me funciono a mi, desde jquery
saludos.